# use AppRTC between android and IOS device

Tags: android, ios, webrtc, apprtcdemo, apprtc

I'm using Sample code of AppRTC for Android and IOS application given by  WebRTC,

Android : https://github.com/njovy/AppRTCDemo/

IOS : https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-ios

When i try to do video chat between Android-Android,Ios-Ios devices ,it is working,But If i try from Android-Ios,Ios-Android,It is not working.

Can anyone help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: Check the socket message format in both code. It should be same for both ios and Android

Comment: http connection link is different in android and ios,now it is fixed

Comment: Have you checked your socket connection messages? Is it in same format for both ios and Android?

Comment: yeah ,messages are same,Problem is with "https://appr.tc" connection url.used different in andorid and ios

Comment: In the interests of providing a reference for other people who wish to benefit from your learning, if you have found a solution, please post an answer, and provide details of the changes (ie code and an explanation) you made to either or both github projects. It would also be useful if you submitted a pull request for your changes to these projects

Comment: I have posted code which i'm using in my Question itself,In comments u will find solution for my issue

Comment: @kavie, When i initialise a video call between Android and IOS then video is freeze at IOS after few seconds. Have you any idea regarding this.

Comment: @kavie can you please share the location of this http connection link that you changes to fix the issue

Comment: @Sana, Sorry , I don't have the code,But Issue is fixed by using same connection URL in android and IOS,Can you please check with this